# Get custom attributes on an R SEXP object when using .Call

Tags: r

I'm making calls to C functions from R using R's .Call interface. Some of the objects I am passing have custom attributes attached to them, and I want to access these attributes from C without having to pass them as separate arguments to the `.Call` function.

For example, consider the simple case of a real number with a custom string attribute:

```
x <- 1
attr(x, "myname") <- "Abiel"
```

One way to get at the "myname" attribute from within the C function is to pass it as a separate argument:

```
.Call("test", x, as.character(attr(x, "myname")))
```

But, I would rather just do

```
.Call("test", x)
```

and then recover the "myname" attribute within the C function. I've been unable to figure out how to do this with the `getAttrib()` function; for instance, the main line of this function below will evaluate to true, indicating a null value.

```
SEXP test(SEXP x)
{
    isNull(getAttrib(x, mkChar("myname")));
}
```

Scanning the R extension writing manual has not helped me much, as all the examples of `getAttrib()` involve predefined symbols, such as `getAttrib(x, R_DimSymbol)`. [This section](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#index-getAttrib-200) describes how to attach a custom attribute to a SEXP object you are creating in C, but not how to get at such a custom attribute that is associated with an object that is being passed into the C function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `install` the attribute to the symbol lookup table.  There isn't an example of using `getAttrib` in section [5.9.4 (Attributes)](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Attributes) of [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html), but there are several examples in [xts.h](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/%2acheckout%2a/pkg/xts/src/xts.h?root=xts&revision=586&content-type=text%2Fplain&pathrev=586).

The code below should evaluate to `FALSE`.

```
SEXP test(SEXP x)
{
    isNull(getAttrib(x, install("myname")));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joshua. I was able to get this to work using getAttrib(x, install("myname"))